# Undefined index error when trying to echo values, I am using functions outside of the class

Tags: php, model, echo

Hey guys I have a question and I still consider myself pretty new at coding, so forgive me if I come off foolish.

I am studying in school as of now and we have a project to build a full stack recreation of craigslist. Any who the problem I am having deals with PHP. I have created an account page with text areas. I would like to echo out the user's information on their so the user can see what he put on and update as he likes. Since my navbar is included on every page, I added the code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])){
      var_dump($_SESSION['logged_in_user']);
      $user = $_SESSION['logged_in_user'];
      var_dump($user);
 }
```

on my account page I figured I can echo it out as 
`<?= $attributes['first_name']?>` within the placeholders. But I keep getting:

> Undefined index: first_name

Also when I `var_dump($user)` I get an protected $attributes array.

In My `Auth` class is where I first defined `$user` as such:

```
public static function attempt($attemptedUsername, $attemptedPassword) {

$user = User::findByUserName($attemptedUsername);
    if ($user == null) {
        return false;
    }

    $validPassword = password_verify($attemptedPassword,$user->password);
    if ($validPassword == true) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in_user'] = $user;            
    }    
    return false;       
}
```

and my `findByUserName` function is in the user class. the code is:

```
public static function findByUserName($user_name){

        // Get connection to the database
        self::dbConnect();

        $stmt = self::$dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');

        $stmt->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name , PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //execute gets its own line, t or false
        $stmt->execute();

        $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // @TODO: Create select statement using prepared statements

        // @TODO: Store the result in a variable named $result

        // The following code will set the attributes on the calling object based on the result variable's contents
        $instance = null;
        if ($result) {
            $instance = new static($result);
        }
        return $instance;
    }
```

Comment: more code please??

Comment: If the array is protected that means it will be inaccessible outside of the class/method it was initially declared in. Are you echoing out that value within the class/method it was declared? Additionally, at the top of your script turn on error reporting with `error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir I updated my question so you can see more of my code. I am echoing the value outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with not being able to access the variable `$user` outside of the static method `attempt()` this can be fixed by declaring the variable globally at the beginning of the method `attempt()` like this:

```
public static function attempt($attemptedUsername, $attemptedPassword) {

global $user;
$user = User::findByUserName($attemptedUsername);
    if ($user == null) {
        return false;
    }

    $validPassword = password_verify($attemptedPassword,$user->password);
    if ($validPassword == true) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in_user'] = $user;

    }

    return false;


}
```

More information can be found on this in the PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).